# Exception while inserting user in Test class

Tags: apex

I have a test class with @testSetup annotation where I am inserting user record. When I am running the test classes parallelly, I am getting unable to Lock row exception.

Since I am inserting user data in different test classes so why would there be a conflict while inserting user, since we are inserting user record in individual test classes.

myTestClass.apex

```
@isTest
public class myTestClass{
    @testSetup static void setupData() {
        User u = Util.getMockUser('passProfileId','passRoleId');
        System.runAs(u)//--> Getting Unable Lock Row exception here if multiple test classes are running in parallel
 { // Insert Test Data }

    @isTest static void testCase1() {...}
```

Util.apex

```
 public static User getMockUser(Id pId ,Id rId) {
      User u = new User(alias = 'mock', email='mockUser@gmail.com',
      emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='User', 
      languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', profileid = pId,UserRoleId=rId,
      timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username= System.now().millisecond() + '@gmail.com');
      return  u; 
   }
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you have any triggers, workflow, flow, or process builder running on the `User` SObject? Any rollup summary fields? Maybe just lookups to `User`? Creating user(s) for the test in your test setup (even though User is a setup object and its data is available in tests) may help alleviate the issue

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to show the code that is inserting Users?

Comment: I've edited the question with code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/salesforce-all-tests-execution.html

“ If multiple test classes are creating users for Unit Tests, using the same profile, the Profile record will face lock issues and the test will fail in parallel.”

Comment: Yea, but we want to do parallel execution to speed up the process. Is there any way to avoid getting this exception?

Comment: You could check ‘Disable Parallel Apex Tests’ checkbox and add the annotation’@isTest(isParallel=true)’ to those tests that can successfully run in parallel. This way, your tests that create user records do not run in parallel but other tests do.

Comment: Right. But we cannot check the 'Disable Parallel Apex Tests' checkbox, as we want to run all tests parallelly.

Comment: Tests that create users, with the same profile, can’t be run in parallel, other tests can use the isParallel annotation to run them in parallel. If it’s a small number of tests that create users, can you use a different profile for each? You may hit the issue again in future when further tests that create a user are written, but it’s an option for now.